# Problema com upload de arquivo com ajax/jquey e laravel 5.7

Tags: ajax, laravel, file-upload

Bom dia amigos, preciso fazer uma requisição em ajax com laravel 5.7, mas por algum motivo o ajax só fica processando e não retorna uma resposta, segue o código:

Ajax:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "{{ url('/gravar/audio') }}",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        audio : jQuery("#audio")[0].files[0]
                    },
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(result){

                        // Definindo estilo da mensagem 
                        mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
                        // Exibindo mensagem
                        mensagem.html(result);
                        botao.button('reset');
                        if(result == "ok")
                        {

                            //limpa formulario
                            $('#form1').each(function () {
                                this.reset();
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (resp) {
                        // Definindo estilo da mensagem 
                        mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
                        // Exibindo mensagem
                        mensagem.html('Erro de processo com servidor!');
                        botao.button('reset');
                    }

                });
            });
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

if ($request->hasFile('audio') ) 
        {
            echo'arquivo valido';
        }
        else
        {
            echo'arquivo não valido';
        }
}
```

Quando não se coloca arquivo retorna arquivo não valido, quando seleciona o arquivo fica processando e não traz uma resposta =(.

Comment: Tenta acrescentar `cache: false,processData: false,`

Comment: Já tentei, mas retorna arquivo não valido =(

Comment: Sao multiplos arquivos?

Comment: um só, um áudio no caso

Comment: Tenta Mudar de `jQuery("#audio")[0]` para `jQuery("#audio")`

Comment: Ele só fica processando, não retorna nada =(

Comment: Verificou no response se mostra alguma coisa?

Comment: Dá um 'espaço' depois do echo

Comment: O response não retorna nada, por isso fica processando que no caso é só em estilo definido antes da requisição.

Comment: dá um `dd($request->all() )`

Comment: ele retorna assim:
[]
isso já com arquivo Selecionado

Comment: Não está enviando o aqruivo

Comment: Percebo que o problema é no jquery, mas não enxergo onde, talves no data... mas já mexi nisso varias vezes e não vai...=(

Comment: Você importou as bibliotecas do jquery?

Comment: sim, uso essas: <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="{{asset('css/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->

Comment: Quando não seleciono algum arquivo ele me retorna arquivo não válido como no método, mas quando seleciono ele não retorna nada, quando o parametro data está assim: audiolaudo : jQuery("#audiolaudo")[0].files[0]

Comment: vou tentar resolver com um plug de upload do jquery

Comment: e se você colocar o dataType: 'json'

Comment: Não estou usando json